# Сокращение слов «стандарт» и «стандартный»

Tags: грамматика, сокращения, условные-сокращения

Какие у слов *стандарт* и *стандартный* общепринятые сокращения?

Ни орфографический словарь Лопатина, ни ГОСТ о сокращениях их не фиксируют.
Мильчин пишет, что у прилагательных обычно отсекается *-ный*, тогда получится *стандарт*., что не намного короче исходного слова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если слово можно сократить отсечением различного количества букв, при его сокращении опускают максимальное количество букв.
Фундаментальный — *фундаментал., фундамент., фундам.*
Следует сократить: *фундам.*
[Сокращение слов и словосочетаний по ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_15)

Стандартный — ***станд.***; стандартное сокращение — ***станд. сокр.***

[Станд. отклонение](https://books.google.ee/books?id=VQlPDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=YR8ucCHVC4&sig=ACfU3U2Sk3L7j5elmqI8WDLuGK73K07bVw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ06XE4KvoAhXmBBAIHQz1B38Q6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false) оценки среднего значения.

Min. = 4, max. = 484, среднее = 70,28, медиана = 47, [станд. отклонение = 73,4](https://books.google.ee/books?id=wBqQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=yH3cyrIpl-&sig=ACfU3U1zOHXveKK-RH4QqmkHoJ64C3IRFw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ06XE4KvoAhXmBBAIHQz1B38Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false) (продолжительность контракта, дни).

Comment: "опускают максимальное количество букв" - без потери различия между похожими словами, конечно же.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Сокращение до двух букв нам никак не подходит, потому что "ст." уже занято и теряется смысл сокращенного слова. А существительное и образованное от него прилагательное сокращаются одинаково.